# DHCP assign wrong Ips

Tags: dhcp

In our company we had an ASA 5510 that we replaced with a FortiGate 200E using two Catalyst 2960 switches in the battery.

Since we made that replacement (ASA to Forti) the switch assigns IP addresses in the range 192.168.1.0/24 when it should assign IPs in the 192.168.3.0/24 range. Catalyst are the ones that do the work of DHCP, not the fortigate.

This happens the first time a device connects but if it disconnects and reconnects about 4 times, it is assigned a correct IP in the range 192.168.3.0/24 but this is quite annoying since users have complained a lot about this inconvenient.

I'm attaching the switches and fortigate config files.

Thanks for your help.

Best regards.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any config files listed. You said that you want the Catalyst switches to be the DHCP servers, but have you ensured you've disabled that functionality in the FortiGate equipment? If the Fortigate 200E as well as a Catalyst switch respond by DHCP, then the address a piece of equipment gets will depend on which response it receives first, which could explain why you sometimes get an address in the desired range, but other times do not.

Fortigate states at [DHCP servers and relays](http://help.fortinet.com/fos50hlp/54/Content/FortiOS/fortigate-system-administration-54/Advanced/DHCP%20servers%20and%20relays.htm):

> On low-end FortiGate units, a DHCP server is configured, by default on
>   the Internal interface

The default IP address range used for DHCP assignments by the Fortigate equpment is 192.168.1.110 to 192.168.1.210.

If you have a Linux system available on your LAN, you can [use dhclient to locate DHCP Servers on the LAN](http://support.moonpoint.com/network/dhcp/dhclient-locate-servers.php). E.g., you could use the command `dhclient -d -nw enp1s4` to find DHCP servers (you would need to substitute the relevant network interface designator on the system on which you run the command for "enp1s4"). Any **DHCPOFFER** lines in the output of the command reveal the IP addresses of DHCP servers on the LAN.